# How to handle the "Share your information?" popup while buying an auto renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, storekit, subscriptions

We have set up successfully auto renewable subscription in an app for buying magazines subscriptions. The app has been validated and is now live, but the inapp product has been rejected because we did not handled correctly the "Share your information?" popup. Basically, when the user answers "don't allow" on that popup, the whole transaction is dropped. On which callback this popup has an effect on?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

Look through all the "share your information" questions here and it seems the answer is negative. However, I tried an app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/odoggy/id427545416?mt=8 (online doggy) and went through its subscription flow. Surprisingly I found the flow is somewhat different from the normal renewable subscription flow, and it does NOT have a "Share your information" popup.

Just wonder how did they achieve this so I believe there must be some way around.